# Publish open source

Tags: licensing, gpl, gpl-3, open-source-definition, android

I use iText in my application
Is the application considered open source if I put the AGPL3 license when publishing the application on Google Play only?, or I must to do something else to considered open source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your [earlier question](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/14204/how-i-make-my-app-open-source) (which you have since deleted) I note that your application has to be published under AGPLv3 because it uses an AGPLv3 library.  In consequence, one of your obligations is to convey your binary under the AGPLv3 licence, but there are others.

One of these is that you must also make the full source for your application available, including that of the associated library, in a comparable manner to the binary.  That doesn't mean you have to put the source up on Google Play as well, but it does mean you have to put it up somewhere, and you have to tell users of the binary about it.  Such conveyance must also be done under AGPLv3, meaning that the recipient is entitled to do what he or she wants with the code, provided he or she also honours the terms of AGPLv3.  This is not the only other obligation, but it's often seen as the largest.

Comment: Thank you, in fact this is my first application and I'm trying to understand how open source is published
I tried to search for the way to do it, but I only found explanations of the meaning of open source
Is there an explanation of the steps to publish it? @MadHatter

Comment: The licence is fairly self-documenting: your obligations with respect to source code are detailed in s6, and a detailed description of how exactly one applies the licence to one's work appears at the bottom, under "*How to Apply These Terms to Your New Programs*".  Does that help?

Comment: yes, thank you very much

Comment: "one of your obligations is to convey your binary under the AGPLv3 licence" - To be more precise, the AGPL v3 does allow you to license your portion of the program under the vanilla GPLv3 instead, but when combined with AGPL software, the obligation to release the source to network users does extend to the GPLv3 software components as well.

Comment: @Brandin you make a good point about the *source*, but AGPLv3 is clear (in s6, which pulls in s5c) that the binary must be AGPLv3 in its entirety.  Since you can't really have a "portion" of a binary, I don't see a problem with that.

Comment: In Section 13 (basically, the "AGPL" unique section), the special wording "notwithstanding any other provision of this License" is used for both paragraphs. In legal terminology, that word is intended to create an exception to other parts of a contract.  So, yes, s5 and s6 imply that the whole thing must be AGPL (source and binary), but s13 says otherwirse with a "notwithstanding" basically to "override" the other provisions that didn't include the "notwithstanding". Well, that's my non-legal reading of it, of course. I'm pretty sure that's the intention of the paragraphs though.

Comment: Not that I disagree with you, but I still don't see how you're going to licence a binary in parts.  What would you say?  "*Locations 0x000-0xe3f in the binary are GPL, 0xe40-0xfe4 are AGPL, and 0xf5e-0xfff are GPL again*"?  AGPLs13 could also give you the right to fly on magic swans, but if there are no magic swans, it's not really a usable right.  It's clear that AGPL doesn't give the right to ship the binary under GPLv3-only, so I don't see much alternative to AGPLv3 only **for the binary**.

Comment: @MadHatter If the program is governed by both AGPLv3 and GPLv3 then one must include both license copies in a binary release to satisfy section 4 (e.g. include both a COPYING.AGPL file and a COPYING.GPL file). In s13 of the AGPL, though, it's clear that when you offer the source, you must include the GPLv3-only portions as well. In the source tree, though, I imagine the intention is that one could have two independent directories there, one with COPYING.AGPL and another with COPYING.GPL, for example. This allows that the GPL-only portion could be shared with a different (non-AGPL) project.

Comment: @Brandin when you suggest "including both licence copies", I don't know what you're imagining with respect to the licence **under which the binary is conveyed**.  Are you suggesting the binary can be taken under either GPLv3 or AGPLv3 at the preference of the receiver?  Because the upstream AGPLv3 licensor won't agree with that.  Are you suggesting the conditions of both apply?  This can't be, because they're incompatible.  I think it's an interesting question, but not one I intend to debate further here.  If you think it worthwhile, I urge you to ask it as a new question in its own right.